# Difference between period and repetition quantifier like "....." and ".{5}" for Regex

Tags: regex

I want to match

> +abcde+

and wrote two regex.

```
\+.{5}\+
\+.....\+
```

According to regex debugger https://regex101.com/, the first one has fewer steps explaining

> .{5} matches any character (except for line terminators)

While the second one says

> . matches any character (except for line terminators)

for 5 times. Does the difference occur because the second one is checking if there is line terminators 5 times?

What is the difference in this step?

Comment: They both check for characters except line terminators 5 times, `.{5}` is just shorthand for `.....`. I don't really understand what you're asking

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/wV5Eb8/1/debugger) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/wV5Eb8/2/debugger)

Comment: Hi @Gurman , what is happening in the 3rd step of second regex? it's matching 5 characters at once. What is the difference between matching 5 characters at once, and matching one character 5 times?

Answer (score 2):

This regex will always be faster:

```
\+.{5}\+
```

because of quantifier `{5}` that makes regex engine match 5 characters in a **single step** rather than match a single character each in **5 steps** as with the `\+.....\+` pattern.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm still confused, what do you mean a single step? What is the difference between a single step matching 5 characters and 5 steps matching each character separately?

Comment: Regex engine taking just one step to match a string vs engine taking 5 steps to match same string. Difference is that for the single step case performance will be better.

Comment: Isn't matching a string anyway have to match with the same 5 characters? What's happening in the engine?? Why is treating it as a string faster?